# cuFFT in Alea GPU

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, cufft, aleagpu

I am using Alea GPU to program on GPU using C# language. I installed Alea 3.0.4 on Visual Studio 2017 project, but I can't find some cuFFT library. On NVidia's website stands cuFFT is part of CUDA Toolkit, so I don't need to download additional CUDA libraries. Do I need to downlaod some additional binding or it is possible to use cuFFT with Alea GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings you're searching are here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Alea.CudaToolkit/

In order for these to work you need to have CUDA Tooklit installed in your machine. (v7.5 or greater)

Here's an example on how to use it:

```
using Alea.CudaToolkit;

int plan;
int padSize = ...
SafeCall(CuFFT.cufftPlan1d(&plan, padSize, cufftType_t.CUFFT_C2C, 1));
```

or...

```
using Alea.CudaToolkit;

int handle;
SafeCall(CuFFT.cufftCreate(&handle));
```

SafeCall is defined as:

```
private static void SafeCall(cufftResult_t status)
{
    if (status != cufftResult_t.CUFFT_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(status.ToString());
    }
}
```